# JavaFX: Images appear and disappear on certain timing points

Tags: animation, javafx

I'm currently trying to make a Rhythm game thats similar to [osu!](https://youtu.be/UYNpkDrCWtA) for my school project. I want to be able to make my circles (images) appear on certain timing points that I choose. I currently have an animation timer set up and randomization of the circle that appears:

```
 new AnimationTimer() {
            public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {
                // Clear the canvas
                Color black = Color.web("#000000", 1.0);
                Color white = Color.web("#FFFFFF", 1.0);
                //bkg
                gc.drawImage(bkg, 0, 0);
                //play feild marker
                gc.setStroke(white);
                gc.strokeRect(200, 22, 877, 683);

                gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                String pointsText = "Points: " + points.value;
                gc.fillText(pointsText, 10, 470);
                String comboText = "Combo: " + combo.value;
                gc.fillText(comboText, 340, 470);
                gc.drawImage(circle,//displays the circle
                        targetData.getX() - targetData.getRadius(),
                        targetData.getY() - targetData.getRadius());

            }
```

My mouse event is done like so:

```
theScene.setOnMouseClicked(
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (targetData.containsPoint(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            //Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))
                            double x = 275 + (int) (Math.random() * ((1000 - 275) + 1));
                            double y = 100 + (int) (Math.random() * ((625 -100) + 1));
                            targetData.setCenter(x, y);
                            mediaPlayer.play();
                            combo.value++;
                            points.value += 100;
                            mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.ZERO);
                        } else {
                            combo.value = 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Currently the circles disappear only when it's clicked. I'm trying to get my circle to appear automatically on a timing that I choose and disappear after a set amount of time. I have my animation timer set up but I have no lead on how I can start timing.

Comment: It's better to use the [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) and [KeyFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html) classes when working with object animations.

Comment: I read up the Documentation on both of those and they seem to be good for automated animations.
I'm trying to get manual animations where I can just insert the time I want stuff to happen. Is there a library out there that does that?